# How to preserve entered input value and display it with label with updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display entered input value with label every time when user click on the test button, the input value should be updated every time when user enter new value in input section that means previous value should be deleted.

here what i have tried but somehow i am not able to display entered value.

```js
       
      $(document).ready(function () {

          var testBtnSrc = document.getElementById("test_btn_src");
            testBtnSrc.addEventListener("click", function(){
              $('inp_src_success').append($('inp_src').val());
            });
                });
```

```html
<title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id = "inp_src_success">
          <label>input value here </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter</label>
          <input  id = "inp_src" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
              placeholder="Source Server Ip:"
              pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
              required onkeypress="myFunction()" />
              <div id = "inp_src1"></div>
              <button id  = "test_btn_src" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test_btn_src').click(function(){
    $('#inp_src_success').text($('#inp_src').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: on every click its appending its not updating or overriding the value

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with this line `$('inp_src_success').append($('inp_src').val());` due to missing `'#'` for the ids.

Secondly, change the code to `$('#inp_src_success label').html($('#inp_src').val());` so that you don't remove the `label` when you are updating with the new value

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var testBtnSrc = document.getElementById("test_btn_src");
  testBtnSrc.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $('#inp_src_success label').html($('#inp_src').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<title></title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id = "inp_src_success">
          <label>input value here </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter</label>
          <input  id = "inp_src" name="txtbox_ip_src" minlength="7" maxlength="15" class="form-control" type="text"
              placeholder="Source Server Ip:"
              pattern="(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
              required />
              <div id = "inp_src1"></div>
              <button id  = "test_btn_src" class="btn btn-primary success" type="button" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-top:7px;">Test</button>
        </div>
```